# What is limiting most traffic on my fiber internet? 100m service getting 15m down, 100m up

Tags: networking, router, internet, isp, fiber

A couple weeks ago I updated my ISP service from 15Mbps to 100Mbps. This is a dedicated fiber line to our server room.

I'm excited to finally be able to try out game streaming like Stadia or Geforce Now. No dice. My speed tests from Ookla come in around 15-18Mbps down and 80-100Mbps up and Fast comes in at 4-5Mbps down. Something is not right. Other speed tests are worse. Stadia speed tests shows 1.5Mbps down. Real world test of trying to game stream, video streaming and downloads also show an issue.

Tried multiple laptops, Chromebooks, phones, desktops on Win and Linux, wired and wireless... All the same. Bought a brand new Unifi Dream Machine router to try (ZyWall is our gateway we have been using for years). Fresh network only 1 device on it, same exact results. Changed to brand new cat6 cables, different WAN and LAN ports.

The ISP asked my to try a laptop direct to their fiber box. Full speed, no issues. Iperf test show fine. Put any router in place and it drops to 15m and 40-60 packet loss.

Here is where it gets fun...Using my current setup or the new unifi router in its place, if I turn on a VPN on a device, I get almost full speed down and a little less up depending on the server connected to. Same on a laptop, chromebook, or android phone. VPN on and I gain most of my speed back. Latency is of course higher and I still can't use game streaming services through a VPN. The ISP has no answer to why that might make a difference.

A further test I thought of was to use my Pixel phone as a usb-ethernet tether into the WAN port of either router. I have bad mobile service out here but on T-Mobile LTE my phone speed tests from Ookla were getting around 29Mbps down. On the tether into the router and running a test on a laptop I got 26.25Mbps down. Faster than I can ever get from the fiber ISP feeding 100-250Mbps in.

Another puzzling piece of information is that while all other speed test tools I can find out there show I have terrible download speeds but good upload, running the Mlabs speed test in google search results comes back perfect almost every time. 105Mbps up/down. Running the Mlabs speed tests from Mlabs' site results in 1.5Mbps down and 105Mbps up. Some real world internet usage is okay- Download a large file or save a movie for offline in a google service and it downlaods at 11+MBs. Large ISO from linux distro or Apple and MS, 150-400kbps!

What could be the cause?

**Summary:**
Consolidated Fiber Adtran 100Mbps <---> Zywall USG-100 plus (or Unifi UDM) <---> Local PC 15Mbps down/ 100Mbps UP on Ookla.

Consolidated Fiber Adtran 100Mbps <---> Local PC 100Mbps down/up on Ookla.

Consolidated Fiber Adtran 100Mbps <---> Zywall USG-100 plus (or Unifi UDM) <---> Local PC *with Express VPN* 85bps down/ 60Mbps UP on Ookla.

Consolidated Fiber Adtran 100Mbps <---> Zywall USG-100 plus (or Unifi UDM) <---> Local PC 100Mbps down/ 100Mbps UP on Google speed test.

T-moblie tether at 29Mbps <---> Zywall USG-100 plus (or Unifi UDM) <---> Local PC 26Mbps down on Ookla and others.

Comment: "Consolidated Fiber Adtran 100Mbps <---> Zywall USG-100 plus (or Unifi UDM) <---> Local PC 100Mbps down/ 100Mbps UP on Google speed test." this suggests the problem is with the other speed tests ...

Comment: What client OS are you using? Does it have TCP ECN enabled? (A month ago, one large cloud provider completely broke their internal network such that if you had ECN enabled, they would mark _every single packet_ as "congestion experienced", and the hosts would dutifully keep reducing cwnd until the speeds reached numbers very similar to the ones you mention.)

Comment: Interesting. I've tested with Linux, windows 7 & 10, Chrome OS, and Android. Chrome, FireFox, and Edge browsers. Results are all the same and repeatable across all devices.    -.  The issue isn't just with speed tests, I can see it in real world uses too.

Comment: so one of the consolidated line techs came out and dropped off an Asus RT-AC1200 router that he used for testing down the road at a cabinet. Putting that in place of either gigabit router gives me closer to full speed. Connecting my routers through theirs gives me the better speeds on my local network as well.

So I'm thinking there must be something this fiber box doesn't like about full duplex 1000m Ethernet or something. The 100m Asus router does better than the ZyWall and Unifi. Getting about 90m up and down.

Still will try to find the reason.